# How to call outer class' super method from inner class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What is the Kotlin equivalent of Java's `OuterClass.super.method()`?

Example (in Java):

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        void someMethod() {
            Outer.super.someOtherMethod();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String someOtherMethod() {
        // This is not called...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the use of Java code?

Comment: Note that a nested class in Kotlin defaults to *static*. For an inner class you have to use the *inner* keyword.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `super@OuterClass.method()` syntax:

```
open class C {
    open fun f() { println("C.f()") }
}

class D : C() {
    override fun f() { println("D.f()") }

    inner class X {
        fun g() {
            super@D.f() // <- here
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to how Java `OuterClass.this` is [expressed in Kotlin as `this@OuterClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html).

Answer (score 5):

According to this section on [inner classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html#inner-classes), you can simply call outer method:

```
class Outer {

    inner class Inner {
        fun foo() { 
            bar() 
        }
    }

    private fun bar() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the equivalent in Kotlin:

```
internal class Outer {
    internal inner class Inner {
        fun myMethod() {
            println(super@Outer.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Blah"
    }
}
```