# how to call super method in listener on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, listener, super

```
    override fun close(){
        var that = this
        view!!.animate().alpha(0f).setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                that.super.close()
            }
        }).setDuration(500).start()
    }
```

how can i call super.close() in listener?

```
that.super.close()
```

i can't *call that.super.close()*

can i solve it?

and i try to like this

```
    override fun close(){
        var that = this
        view!!.animate().alpha(0f).setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                that.closeSuper()
            }
        }).setDuration(500).start()
    }

    fun closeSuper(){
        super.close()
    }
```

it's work. but i want call super.close() at in the listener or in the close() method
please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `super@ClassName.close()`

It works for me when I'm trying to call super.show() in a listener in SampleDialog class, for my case it will be `super@SampleDialog.show()`.

Here's some [references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45373914).

Comment: wonderful! thx!